# Constant in the positive-definite condition of matrices

Tags: matrices

Suppose I have a positive definite matrix $A$, so $$x^TAx \geq C_A|x|^2$$ holds for all $x$.  $A^{-1}$ is positive definite too: $$y^TA^{-1}y \geq C_B|y|^2,$$ is there any way I find the constant $C_B$ in terms of $C_A$?

Comment: Are you assuming $A$ is Hermitian (i.e. symmetric for real $A$)? If so, then $A^{-1}$ is guaranteed to be positive definite if $A$ is.  Also it may be easier to figure out the constants

Comment: Yes it is symmetric and real. I want to find the constant $C_B$

Comment: Well, the largest value for $C_A$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ and the largest value for $C_B$ is the reciprocal of the largest eigenvalue of $A$, so, in general, you cannot write $C_B$ in terms of $C_A$. (Unless you have some special relationship between these eigenvalues.)

Comment: You can't. Just consider a 2x2 diagonal matrix with entries $C_A$ and $C_B^{-1}$ that satisfies $C_B^{-1} \ge C_A > 0$. Aside from this inequality, there is no more information about $C_B$ you can extract from $C_A$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All eigenvalues are positive; in general $C_A$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.  So $C_B$ is $1/\lambda_1$ where $\lambda_1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$.  In general this can't be written in terms of $C_A$ since the largest and smallest eigenvalues in general don't have to be related in any way.